# Change Material Spinner Floating Label Size

Tags: android, css, android-spinner, android-typeface

I'm using material spinner from **https://github.com/ganfra/MaterialSpinner**. I've try using `app:ms_hintTextSize="18sp"` but it only effect the hint size. The font for hint didn't really change. The floating label did change though. But I have no way to change the floating label size. I'm new to android. Your advice and guides are greatly appreciated. Thank you

```
 <fr.ganfra.materialspinner.MaterialSpinner
    app:hintTextAppearance="@style/InputLabel"
    android:id="@+id/spinner4"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:ms_typeface="fonts/OpenSans-Semibold.ttf"
    app:ms_hint="@string/kategori_premis"
    app:ms_alignLabels="false"
    app:ms_hintTextSize="18sp"
    app:ms_baseColor="@color/colorControlNormal"
    app:ms_multiline="false" />
```

Comment: https://github.com/ganfra/MaterialSpinner/issues/48